# Partially share some push constants between different stages

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to figure out how to share some push constants between different shader stages, by setting up multiple push constant ranges. I success when I use one single range with VkFlags VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Fragment shader:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform fragmentPushConstants {
    layout(offset = 0) float time;
    layout(offset = 4) vec4 color;
} u_pushConstants;
```

Vertex shader:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform vertexPushConstants {
    layout(offset = 0) float time;
} u_pushConstants;
```

For this example, how many ranges should I provide vkCreatePipelineLayout with and how should I structure them?

It's working if one single range (0 - 20) with VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL is provided to the pipeline layout info structure. I cannot find any examples what so ever of multi-range usage, except when two different ranges without any overlapping ranges are being used. What's the purpose of ranges at all if I just could use one single range(0 - max) anyway with VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking what the rules of push constant ranges are with regard to accessing them from different shader stages? Because the standard seems to document them effectively. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: My question is if I can and should use one single range(0-20) with VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL if the fragment shader uses time and color from the push constants, and vertex shader only uses time. "time" in this example should use the same memory location, so that i only need to push this variable once. I tried to use two ranges: 1 - (0-20) with vertex and fragment flags, and 2 - (0-4) with vertex flag, but I received some error message telling me that I cannot use the same flag in multiple ranges.